# Convert int to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

I need to convert int to DateTime

```
var a = reader.ValueOrDefault<DateTime>(beginWorkHour);
//........................................................ 

    internal static T ValueOrDefault<T>(this IDataReader reader, int ordinal) {
                if (reader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
                    return default(T);

                return (T) reader.GetValue(ordinal);
            }
```

This code throws an error "Specified cast is not valid".
`reader.GetValue(ordinal)` returns 12.

Comment: What would be the logic in converting 12 to a DateTime?

Comment: I need to fill out the structure WorkingHourns. Do I use TimeSpan instead of DateTime?

Comment: Probably. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

An `int` is an `int`; you still need to fetch it like that, and to be honest it isn't exactly clear how exactly you mean, but at a guess it sounds like you want:

```
DateTime time =
    DateTime.Today.AddHours(reader.ValueOrDefault<int>(beginWorkHour));
```

Answer (score 2):

At the light of your new comment, maybe that's what you're after:

```
var hours = TimeSpan.FromHours(reader.ValueOrDefault<int>(beginWorkHour));
```

Answer (score 1):

So if it returns an int, why are you trying to read it as a DateTime? I would have thought you'd want something like:

```
int hour = reader.ValueOrDefault<int>(beginWorkHour);
DateTime time = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, hour, 0, 0);
```

or something similar. (I'm just guessing, given the variable name.)

How do you *want* the integer to be converted to a date and time?